# Missing Visual Studio Project Template for Xamarin Shared Project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, project-template, shared-project

Visual Studio 2013 with update 4 does not show a shared project template. I only have the Xamarin forms project templates. I just installed a fresh update of Xamarin this morning. Based on what I've found so far, this used to be an issue with VS update 2. Any idea on how to get shared project template to show up?

[image]

Comment: It's an independent extension that you need to download and install: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450

Comment: I saw that and heard it was only for update 2. Future versions should have it.

Answer (score 0):

From Xamarin Support:

> No, there's no optional bits missing. I think Visual Studio Update 4
>   removed the shared project template. It's a Microsoft template, not a
>   Xamarin one. You can still create a Xamarin.Forms app with a Shared
>   Project (that's our template), but they no longer allow you to create
>   an independent shared project.
>
> So, three ways to create one now if you are using Visual Studio 2013:
>
> 1) Switch to Xamarin Studio and create it there and then close it and
>   reopen the solution in VS. VS will recognize the project, it just
>   doesn't have a template to create it anymore. This is probably the
>   easiest approach.
>
> 2) Install the "Shared Project Template" from the Online templates -
>   this is a 3rd party template; I've not tried it but if you want to
>   stay in VS and have the template, it's worth a shot.
>
> 3) Create either a Universal Windows Store app (which uses a Shared
>   Proejct), or a Xamarin.Forms app and then delete all the other
>   projects :)
>
> Alternatively, Visual Studio 2015 (currently in CTP); last time I
>   checked, it still has the project template - you can install that
>   side-by-side with VS2013 and use it as your IDE.

Comment: Install this extension if using Visual Studio 2013 update 4:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450